# Use case for Deliver Order

Tags: uml, use-case, ooad

I have an assignment where i have to create use cases for the deliver order. So here's a summary, the delivery driver said he was given 3 shipping receipts from his company to pick up stocks at the warehouse. He usually arrives at the warehouse at 8am and gives the shipping receipt to the warehouse manager and wait for them to load the stocks in the truck. Once all stocks are in his truck, he then go the first store as stated in his time sheet/schedule. When he arrived there, he gives a shipping receipt for the store manager to sign and then gives a copy to him and he kept a copy as well. After that, he left the store and go onto the next. I did my use cases using visio and this is what i got. Please help me with this as i would gladly appreciate it! [Please click on this to see my use case](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ykVhu.jpg)

Comment: Just in case, what you have on the picture is not a use case, it's a use case diagram.

Answer (score 0):

Well, although this is more a review, rather than a real question, here are some observations:

- Some of your UCs are no UCs:

  - Look at time sheet is merely a step in the including UC, not a UC itself.
  - Similarly Goto Store and Leave Store. They are just actions in scenarios of other UCs, not UCs on their own.
- You don't `<<include>>` an actor. You might just use a simple association. I prefer to stereotype them with `<<secondary>>` or use directed and undirected associations to differentiate between primary and secondary actor relations. However, placing secondary actors just to the right of the boundary seems to be common practice.
- Generally you should ask "what is the added value" and create UCs from that, rather than placing single steps of scenarios like handing out receipts or going to a store. So it's `Deliver goods`, `Create invoice` and the like which are real UCs.

I did not read your description. Instead I'd recommend to look into Bittner/Spence on how to write good use cases. Cockburn is ok too, but I prefer B/S.

Comment: @ThomasKillian thank you for that. I've updated my uml use case and took out the look at time sheet. However, the description is a use case to cover all actions taken from the time an order is loaded onto the truck until the order is delivered and unloaded/signed for by the appropriate Store Manager. I really hope you can help with this. I tried going to other websites and still don't really understand it.

Comment: You don't understand use cases in five minutes. It took me reading the above book and at least one year of practice to get the (almost) full idea behind it. However, after reading the book I had a rough idea about what they meant with "added value".